# Java How do I merge all char from an array of String into a new String?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I'm making a method

```
public static String merge(String... s)
```

This is the input:

```
String a = merge("AM ","L","GEDS","ORATKRR","","R TRTE","IO","TGAUU");
System.out.println(a);
```

Expected Output:

```
ALGORITMER OG DATASTRUKTURER
```

I try to run a loop many times so that it picks up s[0].charAt(index) and appends it to a string for output. The problem I run into is that when I try to run the loop for s[1].charAt(1) it's null, I want it to not get StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, and instead continue to s[2] and appends s[2].char to the String.

How do I go about that?

Comment: use an if statement to check if it is null

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Thanks to the help that was given, the code is running as it's supposed to. I had difficulties to make this work for 2 days, because I tried multiples nested for-loops that ran into the String indexes that had null values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the length of each String before trying to access its i'th character :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int index = 0;
boolean maxLengthReached = false;
while (!maxLengthReached) {
    maxLengthReached = true;
    for (String str : input) {
        if (index < str.length) {
            sb.append(str.charAt(index));
            maxLengthReached = false;
        }
    }
    index++;
}

return sb.toString();
```

Just to clarify, I'm using a boolean `maxLengthReached` to determine when the last character of the longest `String` is appended to the output. If in a full iteration over all the `String`s in the input array we don't find any `String` long enough to have `charAt(index)`, we know we are done.

Comment: Maybe "theEnd" could be renamed to help understand the algorithm.  Maybe something like "characterAdded"

Answer (score 2):

First you need a method to get the longest `String`, something like -

```
private static String getLongestString(String... arr) {
    String str = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].length() > str.length()) {
            str = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Then you can write a nested loop in your `merge()`, something like -

```
public static String merge(String... stringArray) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int pos = 0;
    int len = getLongestString(stringArray).length();
    while (pos < len) {
        for (String str : stringArray) {
            if (str.length() > pos) {
                sb.append(str.charAt(pos));
            }
        }
        pos++;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then you can call it -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = merge("AM ", "L", "GEDS", "ORATKRR", "", "R TRTE", "IO",
            "TGAUU");
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Output is (the requested) -

```
ALGORITMER OG DATASTRUKTURER
```

Comment: You don't *have* to get the longest String.  See @Eran answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does what you need. It works for any number of strings because it uses the varargs (three dots) that allow you to pass any number of strings into `merge`

Use the `getLongest`() to find the length of the longest string.

```
static int getLongest(String... strings) {
    int len = 0;
    for(String str : strings) {
        if(str.length() > len) {
            len = str.length();
        }
    }
    return len;
}
```

Then you merge all the i-th character from each `String` into a `StringBuilder`.

```
static String merge(String ...strings) {

    int longest = getLongest(strings);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < longest; i++) {
        for(String str : strings) {
            if(i < str.length()) {
                sb.append(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

String a = merge("AM ","L","GEDS","ORATKRR","","R TRTE","IO","TGAUU"); 
System.out.println(a);      
}
```

Output

```
ALGORITMER OG DATASTRUKTURER
```

Comment: You don't *have* to get the longest String.  See @Eran answer.

Comment: I never said you have to find the longest String. Agreed, @Eran's answer is nice :)